# FineUploader get filepath for selected file

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader and would like to get the full local path of the file in order to "rebuild" the same folder structur on the server. As far as I understand (and according to the [docs](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#dragAndDrop)) this is only available for DragAndDrop uploads.

However, I cannot get it to work, but I think the issue is with the `dragAndDrop` option itself, as `extraDropZones` AND `reportDirectoryPaths` seem to have no effect. The extra drop zone I added to my html:

```
<div id="extra-dropzone" qq-hide-dropzone>DROP IT</div>
```

does not accept any files. (It is not part of the template, which should be correct?)

Here is my FineUploader init:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    debug: true,
    element: document.getElementById(selector),
    request: {
        params: {
            client: client
        },
        paramsInBody: false,
        endpoint: $('#ajax-route-upload-files').val()
    },
    dragAndDrop:{
        extraDropZones:[
            $("#extra-dropzone")
        ],
        reportDirectoryPaths: true
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    extraButtons: [
        {
            element: document.getElementById("foldersButton"),
            folders: true
        }
    ],
    callbacks: {
        onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
            for (var id in succeeded) {
                console.log(this.getUploads());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

With these settings, shouldn't there be a parameter `qqpath` in my request url, it looks like this `http://localhost:8180/app_dev.php/_ajax/_uploadFiles?client=73&qquuid=c4ab3d19-d7a0-4c0f-ba88-b2961f5b75a2&qqfilename=Doku+AWW.docx&qqtotalfilesize=123450`

Is there any other way to get the folder structure or is there any mistake in my setup? Targeting only FF and Chrome as it is only an internal project.

I think the dev speaks about it [here](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/750#issuecomment-36545535), but I can't see where to put the option elsewhere?